# Why do the training and validation accuracy drop after tuning?

Tags: neural-networks, accuracy, hyperparameter, perceptron, tuning

I thought my MLP (multi-layer perceptron)'s accuracy will increase after tuning. However, the accuracy dropped.

Then someone told me that I should add Dropout layers with 50% dropping.

I did that. However, the accuracy didn't improve.

What could be the explanation?

Comment: Are you using any non robust transformation on your data ahead of the training?

Comment: @Mayeulsgc, what do u mean by "nonrobust transformation"?

Comment: ICA, transformations involving randomness where you didn't pass a seed etc